# detached img's src on IE

Tags: javascript, html, browser

When I have a detached div, and append `img` to the detached div, the image for `src` tag is fetched.
(IE does, chrome doesn't fetch image here)

Is this known behavior of IE and are there any workaround on this issue?

**Edit**

I meant `detached div` as div which was part of DOM but detached using the following jquery call.

`var $div = $('.my-div').detach();`

Comment: *"detached"* being not yet part of the document?

Comment: I want to know why you want to detach a DIV instead of hiding it.

Comment: @jesse, I'm doing the `detach` for faster DOM manipulation in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. IE starts fetching remote resources when they are created, not when they are attached to the DOM. There's no standard on this, so every browser can behave differently. IE does the same with scripts: They're are fetched when you create a script element, but are only executed when you add them to the DOM.